# Shell script password bruteforcing

Tags: linux, bash

Hi first of all apologies if this is poorly worded, will try to explain clearly.

I have a binary named testpassword, usage is probably fairly explanatory.  goes as follows

```
./testpassword hello
```

if hello is **correct** password then output will be

```
pass=correct
```

if hello is **incorrect** password, output will be

```
pass=incorrect
```

I'm a complete beginner at Linux and shell scripting but made a very crude + simple script called bruteforce.sh. to perform a 'brute force' attack with a list of words. contents is as follows

```
./testpassword hello
./testpassword jelly
./testpassword watermelon
./testpassword anotherword  
etc..
```

I ran the following in a new script after quite a bit of goggling for a very rough way to notify me when it's successful

```
./bruteforce.sh 2 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -n pass=correct
```

the output will be something like `12: pass=correct`. where 12 is the line number in bruteforce.sh

when I see this on screen I can ctrl-c and run

```
awk 'NR==12' bruteforce.sh
```

to get the correct pass corresponding to the line number. I was just wondering if there is an easier or cleaner way to do any part of this

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: You should use a tool like John the Ripper. Also security.stackexchange.com is probably better for this.

Comment: JTR is good for cracking password hashes, but it's probably not the tool for the job here. This isn't a security question, it is actually a programming question.

Comment: @Rook I should mention this is a script executed on iOS through SSH. I have used JTR in the past, but not sure how applicable it is in this situation. Thanks for suggestion about security.stackexchange have posted there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps.

```
for i in {1..1000}; do
    (echo -n "$i: " && ./testpassword $i) | grep pass=correct
done
```

This just echos the current password before the script output. Of course, `{1..1000}` can be replaced with the list of words you intend to use.

Comment: Hi thanks very much for answer. Actually I apologise I was very misleading with the description and wrote numbers instead of text, thought it would be simpler to explain but realised it's asking a completely different question. the actual pass would be a string I have edited question to reflect. This is still useful for me so thanks for writing.

Comment: `Of course, {1..1000} can be replaced with the list of words you intend to use` aah Just read this. Let's say I don't just have a couple of words..' I have a list of say 10,000 in a text file, is it possible to link that text file to iterate through those 1 by 1? sorry if that's poorly worded

Comment: Sure. Use a pipe to input values to the program and read them using the `read` Bash command (e.g. `while read password; do; ... ./testpassword $password; done`). Or just use `cat file | while read password`. Lots of ways.

Comment: thanks very much. I got it with the `cat file | while read` command. and also used in combination with your first example to show current password.

Comment: Actually the proper way to write that is `while read ; do ... done <file`.  See also http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: Thanks. I knew you could do it but for some reason forgot the syntax.