# Shell script password auditing

Tags: shell, passwords

I have a binary named ./testpassword  with syntax as below

```
./testpassword pass PASSWORD_GOES_HERE
```

if password is correct output will be

```
pass=correct
```

if incorrect output will be as below

```
pass=incorrect
```

I am brand new to linux and scripting, but with the help of a member on here, made a sample shell script as below

```
    cat passwords.txt | while read x ; do echo -n "$x: " && ./testpassword pass $x ;
done
```

where passwords is a wordlist in txt format.

This works nicely,and If i keep an eye on terminal I can see output as below (continuing for every  line in the word list)

```
jordyt: pass=incorrect
dawder: pass=incorrect
LOL12345: pass=incorrect
warcraft: pass=incorrect
solidussnake: pass=incorrect
0005: pass=correct
```

So in this case, I know 0005 is my password, my question is, Is it possible to stop the program when password is found, or to automatically show the password somewhere?. If I am to walk away from the screen I lose track of what the password was as the screen will continue attempting passwords and scrolling down

the previous way I was doing was like this [Shell script password bruteforcing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614318/shell-script-password-bruteforcing) . It worked as I could walk away and come back later and see that the password had been cracked and then ctrl+c the program, except it was a bit of a long winded way of doing things. after I had to manually search for the line number in the wordlist corresponding to the cracked password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the execution of `./testpassword pass $x` in a variable doing:

```
cat passwords.txt | while read x ; do result=`./testpassword pass $x` ; echo -n "$x: $result" ; done
```

Then, you can compare $result to the string "pass=correct" and break the loop if it finds the string this way:

```
if [[ "$result" == *pass=correct ]]; then break; fi
```

Put all together:

```
cat passwords.txt | while read x ; do result=`./testpassword pass $x` ; echo -n "$x: $result" ; if [[ "$result" == *pass=correct ]]; then break; fi ; done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for response. I am trying to figure it out now

Comment: I have edited the answer to show you how to test the string and break the loop

Comment: Appreciate you breaking it down very clearly. At the moment I've tested and the command successfully runs, but doesn't seem to break when correct output is found. it will continue execution as usual. I've also tried modifying $result to point to incorrect password and doesn't break

Comment: OK I managed to do get it to break by changing to `result=`./testpassword pass $x $x 2>&1 >/dev/null`. perfect. now the only 1 thing left is that the output now longer goes line by line down the screen, they go horizontally and looks a bit messy

Comment: quite easy, just use `echo -e` this way: `echo -ne "$x: $result\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `testpassword` script, so it will return 0 in case of success and some other value in case of failure. After that, you can rewrite your loop as follows:

```
cat passwords.txt | while read x; do
    echo -n "$x: " && ./testpassword pass $x && break
done
```

Comment: thanks for response. the testpassword is a binary file. I assume I won't be able to change the exit code in that case

Comment: In that case replace the inner loop with `echo -n "$x: "; res=$(./testpassword pass $x); echo $res; [ "$res" == "pass=correct" ] && break; done